# Service for selling ERC20 Token directly for fiat?

Tags: erc-20, altcoin

So currently our ERC20 token is trading on several DEX's. There is quite some volume but some potentially interested people have given us feedback on the process being a little bit too much for them. (Sign up to a CEX, buy ETH, send ETH to DEX, trade ETH for Coin, send Coin to Wallet).

Are there any services to let people directly buy the token for fiat?

It does not have to be a full-blown (Centralized) exchange. Just a buy button and a price would suffice. But in a trustworthy way? Either with Ideal, Skrill, Paypall, Creditcard or something similar.

We can not offer tokens ourselves cause I think then we are actually entering the space of exchanges.

Comment: I believe that you can do this via https://www.bancor.network/, but not with all types of credit cards.

Comment: Thanks but it looks like that actually adds another step, exchanging BTC or ETH for BNT first.

Comment: Partially correct; you can exchange ETH for any ERC20 listed on this network.

Comment: My bad, thanks. That still is similar to a DEX in terms of number of steps.

Comment: If your token is popular enough you might be able to reach an agreement with a centralized exchange that can list your token. Other than that I see no way out.

Comment: You can create your own such service. (1) payment gateway to accept payment (2) automated system to send ERC20 tokens to users. So, this way you can send tokens to users just in one click (more background process and security management though)

Answer (score 1):

Some services out from my head, not in a particular order

Changelly

ShapeShift

Crypto.com wallet

Note that all services need integration with a cryptocurrency exchange, like Binance, that provides the underlying liquidity. Then the users of these services need to perform KYC.

Answer (score 1):

bancor is based on simplex, that provides KYC services plus credid card servcies. So to comply with KYC, it might be a good choice to move with simplex directy.

If you make your KYC yourself, it's may be better to assemble you payment gateways yourself and provide it directly.